# How do I detect the filesystem type from Java on Linux?

Tags: java, jna

I want to check that a filesystem is ntfs or fat32 and so on, and when i want to run it i get this:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Kernel32': Native library (linux-x86-64/libKernel32.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/nszabo/workspace/Vidux/bin/, file:/home/nszabo/workspace/Vidux/external/common/org-json-2010-12-28.jar, and so on...`

I tried this:

`java -Djava.library.path="VolumeInformation.java"> -jar /usr/share/java/jna.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.java.jna.jar`

What can be a problem? Thanks all for the help!

**UPDATE:**

here is my code where drop the error.

```
    Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetVolumeInformation(
            "C:\\", 
            lpVolumeNameBuffer, 
            nVolumeNameSize, 
            lpVolumeSerialNumber, 
            lpMaximumComponentLength, 
            lpFileSystemFlags, 
            lpFileSystemNameBuffer, 
            nFileSystemNameSize);
```

next one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getFileSystemName();
}
```

and the final in Kernel32.java:

```
public Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS);
```

Comment: I guess, There is something wrong with the "/usr/share/java/jna.jar" path.

Comment: but in there is a jna.jar... ll command: 155001 Aug 18  2014 jna.jar

Comment: maybe it will help when you post your code which throws the error message.

Comment: The error message looks like you try to use a Windows API Kernel32 on a Linux box?

Comment: Is this running on windows or linux?

Comment: linux, but if it is bad how can i do that a filesystem ntfs,fat or wchich i use?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can run the mount command with Runtime.exec() and parse the output to check which filesystems are mounted and which type they have.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run Windows API functions on linux.  You need to call filesystem inspection functions appropriate to linux instead.

To do so requires either a separate mapping ([`getfsfile("/path/to/fs")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getfsent.3.html) and look at the fs_vfstype field within the returned structure), or you can invoke the `mount` command as a process and parse its results as suggested by @ralf-m-petter.